# Tailwind: Split layout with a video component?

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm trying to build this split layout with Tailwind and React:

[image]

But after countless attempts, I only managed to achieve this layout. Using the exact same styling with an image instead of a video works, but I'm unaible to scale / stretch the video container.

[image]

I'm under the assumption that this might be related to the width and height properties of the ReactPlayer component, but every attempt to set these at different percentages in order to improve the layout failed.

```
<div className="bg-green w-full md:w-1/2  order-first lg:order-last md:order-last">

<ReactPlayer
url= {TennisVideo}
className="object-contain h-screen md:h-screen lg:h-screen xl:h-screen w-full "
width='100%'
height='100%'
playing={true}
muted={true}
loop={true}
config={{ youtube: { playerVars: { disablekb: 1 } } }}>
  
  </ReactPlayer>

  
  </div>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?
https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-hugle-vpuvr?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that `object-contain` is a culprit, and should instead be `object-cover`. More info in the docs [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/object-fit#cover)